# Opening a Dynamics CRM 2013 form in Outlook instead of CRM

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm

thank you for taking the time to read this. I have a client who wants a button to be placed on the Appointment form that, when clicked, opens a copy of the Appointment form inside of Outlook as opposed to CRM. I've been looking at Microsoft.Crm.Outlook.SDK and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook but neither of of them seems to have any methods that jump out as being able to accomplish this. Has anyone run into this that could possibly point me towards an example or a decent tutorial? I've been checking google and the msdn as well but I'm not having any luck. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The CRM client can be accessed through a browser or through outlook. If a user is accessing CRM through the outlook client and he opens a link to an appointment - then that appointment will open within outlook. If the user is accessing CRM through a web browser I do not think it is possible to launch an appointment though the web browser directly. 
What you could do is generate an outlook appointment (.ics) file - through code - when the user opens this file it will open in Outlook by default. There is a format for creating iCalendar or outlook appointment (.ics) files  - just google it - plenty of examples of creating them though code.